# How to restrict user from accessing directory but not the files which are inside it

Tags: apache, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have one html file which include images which are uploaded on server. I include them in this way . Lets say the path of files are Images/img1.jpg, Images/module1/img1.jpg and these are relative paths. and If I go to my browser and type "domain.com/Images/img1.jpg" and "domain.com/Images/modul1/img1.jpg" these files should be accessible. But when I type "domain.com/Images/" or "domain.com/Images/module1" the they should not be accessible. It should show me access denied in these cases.

Comment: you should add a little more detail about what you want, reading it sounds very confusing. Also how you "include" files is not clear also. Do you copy them? A process uploads them? (in this case which user runs that process). Maybe you should go item by item saying if you want them world readable or not and which you want readable and writable and which you don't want to be readable or writable.

Comment: @ezra-s I have one html file which include images which are uploaded on server. I include them in this way <img src = "path of file">. Lets say the path of files are  Images/img1.jpg, Images/module1/img1.jpg and these are relative paths. and If I go to my browser and type "domain.com/Images/img1.jpg" and "domain.com/Images/modul1/img1.jpg" these files should be accessible. But when I type "domain.com/Images/" or "domain.com/Images/module1" the they should not be accessible. It should show me access denied in these cases. Is it clear to you ?

Comment: You mean you do not want them to be listed when one requests the directory? If that is so, configure httpd for the main directory and subsequent ones if you have defined with "Options -Indexes"

Comment: @ezra-s Yes I want to show the user "access denied" when one request the directory. Could you please help me how can I configure httpd for the same.

Comment: I mentioned it in me previous comment, in the directory directive inside Apache HTTPD, set Options -Indexes, if you want you can show how you have it (modify the description of your problem) and I will fix it for you with an Answer

Comment: @ezra-s I have edit the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you seem to describe is to avoid Directory Listing in apache, you just have to set the directory like this:

```
<Directory /full/path/to/Images>
    Options -Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Additionally you could add a welcome page for those directories with `DirectoryIndex index.html`

This configuration will propagate in all subdirectories so you do not need to define them in all subdirectories one by one, so unless you already have a configurating for a subdirectory overriding this one, this one will apply further down in the directory tree.

Note: If you are using 2.2 you should use "Allow from all" instead of "Require all granted"